# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required when installing nltk==2.0.5

Tags: pip, nltk

When installing nltk==2.0.5, I get the error `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required`. Really, I'm trying to install `newspaper`, but it's failing when trying to install this package.

A minimal Dockerfile to reproduce the issue:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip

# problem occurs with or without the following line
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

CMD ["pip", "install", "nltk==2.0.5"]
```

Comment: it's because of https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031714.html

Comment: `pip install nltk==3.2.5` works

Comment: @samuel So how did you fix this?

Comment: I ended up installing `newspaper` from my fork: `pip install git+https://github.com/ssaamm/newspaper.git@python-2-requirementsupdate`

Comment: @SamuelTaylor It looks like this branch in your repository has been deleted though in the meantime.

Comment: But also, it's conveniently been merged! https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/pull/465

Answer (score 19):

1. `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/nltk/nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz`
2. `tar -xzf nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz`
3. change `DEFAULT_URL` from http to https in `nltk-2.0.5/distribute_setup.py`
4. pip install that directory, or if you trust I did the above then do: 
   `pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/jdimatteo-personal-public-readaccess/nltk-2.0.5-https-distribute.tar.gz`

**Edit**

If the wget link is broken, download [ntlk 2.0.5 from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk/2.0.5)

Comment: The pypi version seems to be removed. Python community is a strange place. really.

Comment: It's still available on pypi at https://pypi.python.org/packages/50/9e/39418026bf8013bbc2852c7aec3fb21e4339f6cd694934496d67a19b53b8/nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz#md5=c3f77cc1bf6c6bc85db6629b7d23c3b9 (or browse for it in [the /simple/nltk listing](https://pypi.python.org/simple/nltk/#downloads).

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans The package is not removed, the link is just broken.

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy You are Looking at this 4 months later. It was fixed since and the originally mentioned URL might not be correct by now. and Yes, 2.0.5 can now just be downloaded with no issues. Until the next nltk issue.

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans your remark about Python community made me into tears, so just edited.

Comment: I faced some issues with these steps. This is what worked for me:

1. `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/50/9e/39418026bf8013bbc2852c7aec3fb21e4339f6cd694934496d67a19b53b8/nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz#md5=c3f77cc1bf6c6bc85db6629b7d23c3b9`

2. Same as OP.

3. Same as OP.

4. `pip install ./nltk-2.0.5`

Comment: here is the link.
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/9e/39418026bf8013bbc2852c7aec3fb21e4339f6cd694934496d67a19b53b8/nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

This is a derivative of @JDiMatteo's answer above that worked for me.

1. `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/50/9e/39418026bf8013bbc2852c7aec3fb21e4339f6cd694934496d67a19b53b8/nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz#md5=c3f77cc1bf6c6bc85db6629b7d23c3b9`
2. `tar -xzf nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz`
3. Change `DEFAULT_URL` from `http` to `https` in `nltk-2.0.5/distribute_setup.py`
4. `pip install ./nltk-2.0.5`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in case anybody is still facing the issue.

pip install git+https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper.git@python-2-head